# How to integrate css from node_moduels in anguler2 seed project?

Tags: css, angular, leaflet

I'm integrating [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) into an [anguler2-seed](https://mgechev.github.io/angular2-seed/) project.

Basically it was just npm intalling leaflet and using in a leaflet component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.js';

declare let L: any;

/**
 * This class represents the leaflet integration.
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'el-leaflet',
    template: '<div id="leaflet-map"></div>',
    styles: [`
        #leaflet-map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    `]
})
export class LeafletComponent {}
```

To include the leaflet css file I add it to my `project.config.ts`:

```
this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
  ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
  {src: 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css', inject: true}
];
```

This works fine. But feals wrong to me. Because this causes the `leaflet.css` to be loaded for the whole application, even if the map is never used. Is there a way to isolate the inclution of `leaflet.css` in the leaflet component.